# Is there a way to dynamically negate the List in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I require to generate two reports (Report 1 and Report 2) both are similar in every way except the product listed in it. Report 1 will have say two products (Product 1 and Product 2) and Report 2 will have remaining products (i.e.excluding Product 1 and Product 2).

I have currently made two function where I have actually duplicated the logic the only diffrence is in first I check if product is Product 1 and Product 2 (i.e I check "in [Product1, Product2]") and in second I negate the condition (i.e I check "not in [Product1, Product2]")

Is there a way I can use same logic for both reports just the condition "in List" and "not in List" changes based on some parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Add an additional flag as your "some parameter" and compare the result of the is-in-list test to that:

```
must_be_in_list = True
...
is_in_list = (x in [p1, p2])
check_passes = (is_in_list == must_be_in_list)
```

Comment: Thanks very elegant, I should have thought of it.